# How can I move an image to the right side of the footer?

Tags: css, html, webforms, css-float, footer

I thought floating right would shove an element to the far right side, but it doesn't. Here's my HTML:

```
<footer>
    <p class="float-left">&copy;<%: DateTime.Now.Year %></p>
    <img class="breathingRoom" src="Images/axXAndSpaceLogo.jpg" alt="Across Time and Space logo" width="128" height="80" />
    <a class="breathingRoom" href="http://www.awardwinnersonly.com/humans.txt" target="_blank">
      <img src="Images/humanstxt-isolated-orange.gif" alt="Humans dot text logo" width="105" height="46" /></a>
    <img class="float-right" src="Images/Logo-BannerSmall_1_.gif" />
</footer>
```

...and here's the relevant CSS:

```
.float-left {
    float: left;
}

.float-right {
    float: right;
}

.breathingRoom {
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-top: 4px;
}
```

...but the final image butts up against the humans.txt image, instead of hugging the east side of the screen. What do I need to do to elbow it stage right?

html5 css footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
footer {
  position: relative;
}
.float-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;  /* no float necessary */
}
```

Since you haven't said any conditions for the rest of the elements, you actually don't need to float them left unless you want the image and text inline.

Answer (score 1):

I made a short sample with your code :

[JSFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/C7CsR/1/)

The right picture is at the right.

So what's wrong ?

I think it a doctype problem, if you don't have a doctype, the 'footer' markup is not well understood by browsers. Add a Doctype definition in the first line of your html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Or You can add in your css :

```
footer{
   display:block;
   width:100%;
}
```